# What C# conventions are there for combining parent and child method outputs?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, method-chaining, method-signature

I'm learning C# after many moons in JavaScript land (just for some reference).

I read the C# [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance) introduction as well as when and when not to use [new/override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords) and (excuse the ignorance) am wondering if there are best practices or conventions for combining the output of parent and derived class methods that have the same signature.

An example (not whole file, just samples) from the game I'm building:

```cs
// CharController
using static TargetController;
public abstract class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour, ICharacter
{
      public virtual TargetTypes Target() {
        return TargetTypes.Character;
    }
}
```

```cs
// PlayerController
using static TargetController;
public class PlayerController : CharacterController, IPlayer
{
      public override TargetTypes Target()
    {
        return base.Target() | TargetTypes.Player;
    }
}
```

```cs
// EnemyController
using static TargetController;
public class EnemyController : CharacterController, IEnemy
{
      public override TargetTypes Target()
    {
        return base.Target() | TargetTypes.Enemy;
    }
}
```

The `TargetType` enum has flags enabled and types are set in powers of two so that values can be combined using the bitwise OR operator.

I am assuming (given my current understanding) that if I was to derive a class from, say, the EnemyController and defined an identical method that returned `base.Target() | TargetTypes.Small` (for example) I would get these three types when calling the derived (leaf) class Target method: `Character, Enemy, Small`.

Please feel free to tear me a new one (with wisdom and on good authority, please!) if this approach is just all wrong or there is some established convention for combining outputs of methods with the same signature (i.e. perhaps I should be chaining the methods somehow?).

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you'll find the general inheritance conventions are very similar to JS ES6 classes. There are obviously differences based on language capabilities (abstract vs concrete class, access modifiers, overriding vs hiding, etc), but the general idea and class design approach are very similar.

Comment: I don't want to 'tear you a new one', but I do want to point out that 'best practices' and 'how should I be writing this code' questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow due to be opinion-based topics.

Comment: I'm asking about a specific way to do a specific thing (combine outputs of parent and child methods with the same signature), and if there's authoritative solutions to such a problem. That's fair game for S/O - mentioning the term "best practices" or asking for input based on good authority is precisely what makes it _not_ just about every man and his dog...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Although you should probably either rename it to `GetTargetTypes()` or make it a property:

```cs
public abstract class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour, ICharacter
{
    public virtual TargetTypes TargetTypes => TargetTypes.Character;
}

public class PlayerController : CharacterController, IPlayer
{
    public override TargetTypes TargetTypes => base.TargetTypes | TargetTypes.Player;
}
```

Note: You might need to use the fully qualified name to prevent confusion between the enum name and the member name, if you give them the same name (which is a [common practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).)

Comment: Great! Thank you. Am I correct in assuming that the `base` of a derived class is it's parent, even if that parent is one in long inheritance chain (i.e. base is not the root class)?

Comment: @GrayedFox Correct.

Comment: @GrayedFox But in general you should prefer "composition over inheritance" (google that) and avoid long inheritance chains.